# How do I receive an input from scanf and make numbers of structures accordingly?

Tags: c, scanf

I want to receive an input from the keyboard, for example:
Enter the number of countries:

My struct is

```
struct country {
  char name[20];
  int population;
  float area;
  float gdp;
  char continent[20];
}
```

and if the user types 3, I want 3 of those structs. How do I declare them?

Answer (score 0):

You read the number from user input, then you create the according number of structs at runtime:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct country {
    char name[20];
    int population;
    float area;
    float gdp;
    char continent[20];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    unsigned int count;
    scanf("%u", &count); //read count
    struct country *countries = calloc(sizeof(struct country), count); //allocate memory for count country structs
    countries[0].area = 1.0f; //now you can access the structs like array elements
}
```